# Fatal error : class 'LoginForm' not found in Zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'am stuck in zend framework, when I try to login i get this error message saying :Fatal error: Class 'Anuncios\Form\LoginForm' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\data\apps\http__default__\0\AplicacaoMediador1\1.0.0_86\module\Anuncios\src\Anuncios\Controller\AnunciosController.php on line 28
at this line exactly i instantiate an object of the class LoginForm which is located in the " Form " folder .

Here's the controller code:

```
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

use Anuncios\DTO\Credenciais;
use Anuncios\Infrastucture\Services\ImoServices;
use Anuncios\Form\LoginForm;

class AnunciosController extends AbstractActionController
{
public function indexAction()
{
    return array();
}

public function loginAction()
{
    $form = new LoginForm();
    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Login');

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {

        session_start();
        ImoServices::Logout();

        $credenciais = new Credenciais();
        $form->setInputFilter($credenciais->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $credenciais->exchangeArray($form->getData());

            if( ImoServices::Login($credenciais) )

                // Redirect to values
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('anuncios', array('controller'=>'anuncios', 'action' => 'values'));
        }
    }
    return array('form' => $form);
}
```

Here's the LoginForm class:

```
namespace Anuncios\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class LoginForm extends Form
{
public function __construct($name = null)
{
    // we want to ignore the name passed
    parent::__construct('credenciais');

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'username',
        'type' => 'Text',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Username',
        ),
    ));
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'password',
        'type' => 'Password',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Password',
        ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'type' => 'Submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'value' => 'Go',
            'id' => 'submitbutton',
        ),
    ));
}
}
```

Comment: What is the full namespace of the `AnunciosController` class?  What is the full path & filename of the `Anuncios\Form\LoginForm` class?

Comment: The namespace is `Anuncios\Controller`. By full namespace do you mean everthing? Then it would be `module\Anuncios\src\Anuncios\Controller\AnunciosController` and the full path for the `Anuncios\Form\LoginForm` class is  `module\Anuncios\src\Anuncios\Form\LoginForm`. The file name is  `LoginForm`.

Comment: All of that looks good.  To help narrow down the problem, see if the `Credenciais` class can be accessed by the `AnunciosController` class, by copying the `$credenciais = new Credenciais();` line to directly above `$form = new LoginForm();`.  Then attempt to log in.  If you receive the same error message, then you know the problem is with the `LoginForm` class.  If you receive a different error message suggesting that the `Credenciais` class cannot be loaded, then there's a broader autoloading problem at play here.

Comment: Can you provide code of **module.config.php** of Anuncios module??